# WordPress - Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions stays proportional

Tags: php, wordpress

Whole week I'm struggling why WordPress don't crop all thumbnails properly, because I have checked "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)". 
Some images are cropped to exact size, but some of them are re-sized only, especially portrait images.

I didn't change anything else, this happens right after installation of WordPress 4.0 .

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Tried, but this happens to new images and also they stays like they are after "regenerate-thumbnails" usage.

Comment: Well then my guess is those images you are having problems with are **smaller** than the exact dimensions specified - wordpress will not upscale images, but your css might. Check the actual size of the thumbnails produced, and the input images

Comment: You are right, I didn't realized that I'm using small images.

Comment: Thought so. Glad i could help you